# How could I add an epigraph to each chapter in classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis, epigraphs

I am using `classicthesis` for my Master's Degree dissertation and I would like to add epigraphs in each chapter. My idea is to include a simple sentence before the text. Any suggestions to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question will answer yours.